# Tools to design good looking HTML forms

Tags: html, css

Are there any free tools through which I can design beautiful HTML Forms?

Comment: And by "design" do you mean "copy and paste someone else's work?"

Comment: No. Drag and Drop intuitive controls, change Form's look 'n feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quite recent article that details some of the HTML5 form features, along with making a nice looking form. http://24ways.org/2009/have-a-field-day-with-html5-forms

Comment: The article is great but be aware that HTML5 is not fully supported yet by all browsers.

Comment: Pekka, what exactly is your point here? You can use the new HTML5 input field `type`s without any problem whatsoever in browsers who don’t support them — they’ll just render as ordinary input fields.

Comment: @Mathias, it's possibly worth pointing out, simply because expectation may, as with all things xhtml/css, be different from the rendered output. If the OP is new to (xhtml/css) forms, this may be an issue worth raising,

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any tools, but there is a very nice basic article on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms/) that might get you started.

Answer (score 3):

http://wufoo.com/

Makes reasonably nice forms, will write all the HTML for you, make it easy to insert in your page, and even creates the validation js. If you just want to use it for the HTML code, its free - if you want to use them to host your forms and have any real amount of traffic its a paid service.

You get a certain amount of traffic even in the free version, I forget how much.

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys, I found one simple tool. It works and is free.

http://www.phpform.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Wordpress, you might also like to check out Gravity Forms. I've found them to strike a nice balance between simplicity and customisation. They have a solid user base, are reasonably priced and offer a good level of support in my experience:

http://www.gravityforms.com/